# How to submit an archive only for 64-bit iOS devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit

I'm trying to archive a content blocker application. Because the API is only available on 64 bits, I've added this in the `info.plist` of the app:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>arm64</string>
</array>
```

This value is only in the application target, not the content blocker target. When sending my application to the App Store using Xcode Organizer it returns this message:

`ERROR ITMS-90503: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist must only contain the arm64 slice."...`

I've checked online and this error looks new and undocumented, do you know what should I do to remove it?

Comment: You need to connect a 64 bit device and change the setting to "build active architecture only" to "Yes", but you may still have a problem...  If you set the target iOS to 9, it may work but earlier targets will definitely give you an error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As dsiddhpura suggested, the solution is to check the valid architectures in the build settings. Be sure to have selected "All" in the right top-right corner and verify that there is only `arm64` in the valid architectures.

It should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

your plist must be look like that:

[image]

Set **Build Active Architecture Only** set to **Yes**. And you validate build product look like that:

[image]

Comment: It was like that but I archived another version after looking carefully at these two values, I still have the same error as in the question.

Comment: i fixed it by above answer when i upload update of my app and that change by use same code in new version of xcode.

Comment: yes i am but the issue have to fix by create this change make armv7 at plist instead of arm64

Comment: You shouldn't modify "Build Active Architecture Only" option. It should stay YES for Debug and NO for Release like default values. The second part is unnecessary and only gonna make things slower when in Debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload apps to the App Store with that requirement. The only requirement you can have is lowest iOS target. So if you specify iOS9 (latest) then the iPhone 4s is still able to download your app. iPhone 4s runs the 32-bit architecture.

Comment: If I remove the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities it returns `Error 90533: Missing architecture (...) requires a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities value of 'arm64'`.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can remove the architectures other than "arm64" or you can limit the deployment target to 8.0

Comment: The first solution would be perfect, how can I tell Xcode to do that?

Comment: Go to Build Settings -> Valid Architectures and remove others keeping only one in that: "arm64"

Also make sure that "Architectures" should not be Standard Architecture. I should also have only "arm64".